# Not Found: Requested url was not found on this server. AWS django elastic beanstalk

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Hello let me apologize in advance since I am a beginner and this may be a very simply fix but I just launched my first elastic beanstalk server trying to host my portfolio. I followed the tutorial laid out by amazon at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html but something must've gone wrong. I'll include a picture of my hierarchy, my applications.py and my urls.py if you need anything else don't hesitate to ask any help is very appreciated thanks!

```
"""
WSGI config for Portfolio project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'Portfolio.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

There is my application.py and now my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('sudoku/', views.sudoku, name='sudoku'),
]
```

and finally my hierarchy

[image]

Comment: What URL were you trying to access?

Comment: I guess I'm just trying to go to my index.html so my first path or just the url elastic beanstalk gave me when I deployed